# SQL statement - show results after two weeks

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

TO do an SQL statement where donations were given after more than two weeks that have been donated and which people (who took donation) were involved

Apart from this, mysql workbench is saying unconnected, what can i do please?

SELECT 
FROM Patient, Donation
WHERE donationID = patientID
ORDER BY donationDate > 14;

Answer (score 0):

No completely sure, but at least the current date must be in the selection:

SELECT FROM Patient, Donation 
WHERE donationID = patientID 
ORDER BY donationDate > (sysdate-14);

In this case sysdate would be the current date (oracle) minus 14 days

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below, use explicit join

```
SELECT 
FROM Patient p join Donation d
on p.patientID=d.donationID 
where  donationDate >= date(current_date()-14);
```